# Is it possible to go back to a previous step while debuggin with vdebug?

Tags: php, codeigniter, vim, xdebug

I've checked the manual and only see options to 'step into' or 'step over' but no kind of 'step back' function.  Is there way to go in reverse or a possible script to implement this?

Comment: Vdebug being only a front end for an actual debugger (xdebug), that "step back" feature needs to be available in the debugger itself. Are you sure that's the case?

Comment: xdebug doesn't have a step back function.  It would be nice to have though.